# How does a unit test know when to pass or fail?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I'm reading "Dependency Injection for .NET" and following along with some of the samples in the book and it lead me to a question about unit testing.
How does a unit test know when to `pass` or `fail`?
Not sure why, but I've always assumed you needed to Assert something and if the Assert is `true`, the unit test passes otherwise the test fails.

However, that seems to be not the case. Look at this sample below (using `NUnit` and `Moq`).

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_UserProvidedMessage()
    {
        Mock<IMessageWriter> m = new Mock<IMessageWriter>();

        Salutation s = new Salutation(m.Object);

        s.Exclaim("use this message silly");

        m.Verify(w => w.Write("use this message silly"));
    }
```

The unit test output is controlled through the `Mock.Verify` method. I understand that for this example but now I'm questioning what I know about unit tests passing or failing.

How does a unit test know when to `pass` or `fail`?
What criteria does the unit test framework use to determine if the output is `pass` or `fail`?

Comment: It passes when you missed the bug and when it fails your test infrastructure is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unit test fails if it throws an exception.

All assertion methods and mock verifiers throw special exceptions that provide more detail about the failure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing maybe the `Verify` method throws an exception if it can't verify, and this causes the unit test to fail. And if there's no exception it means it passed.